# Symfony: so finally how to use custom core PHP library on v4-v5?

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

So subject is the question. Yes, I've searched this forum and googled too. All I've got - useless Symfony docs and casts, some general advises, cli-s and nothing case specific. Maybe yahoo or duckduck could help better?

Everyone is talking about bundles, about how it is important to create them, probably because under the hood Symfony is pushing users away from custom libraries, but no one is actually explains how to start using a bundle - how to start calling its methods.

No, my library is not a composer or whatever package. No, library methods do not return Response objects. No, I am not dealing with composer or recompilations or cli (I use Composercat). No, I will not put library to github or packagist to load it via composer or whatever because it is private library.

Sorry about emotional off-topic.

About the case: I've put my library into the folder

```
src/lib/MyLibrary.php
```

I suspect that library class is autoloaded, because if I do not extend Controller with it (if I declare `class MyLibrary` instead of `class MyLibrary extends Controller`) - Symfony spits "class name in use" error.

So question: in my controller how to call library method?

`$this->get('MyLibrary')` doesn't work.

`echo print_r($this)` doesn't show MyLibrary in this registry too.

Looks like library file is loaded but not registered and/or instantiated. If it is so, then where to point Symfony to register it?

Comment: Just to clarify, src/lib/MyLibrary.php contains a class called MyLibrary and you want to know how to instantiate it?

Comment: Yes: contains this class, and almost yes: I want to call class MyLibrary methods in my Symfony app.

Comment: @RomanK: I think you will need to create a new Service using `services.yaml`. The services defined in this file are auto-loaded by Symfony depending upon the provided service configuration. Then you will easily be able to do `$this->get("<service_id>")` from your controller. Go through https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html. Ensure that you are referring to the documentation according to your Symfony version

Comment: @verisimilitude As a rule, using $this->get is discouraged in the latest version of Symfony.  I think this question is more about how to use an independent library inside of a Symfony app and not really about services.  Could be wrong.

Comment: Oh.. I see. Thanks for clarification. I misinterpreted this  `No, I will not put library to github or packagist to load it via composer` to mean that the OP does not want to use `composer.json` to auto-load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So most of this question is really about how php manages classes.  Not so much about Symfony.  But that's okay.

To start with it would be best to move project/src/lib to just project/lib.  Symfony has some scanning stuff going on in the src directory and you really don't want to have your library mixed up in it.

So:

```
# lib/MyLibrary.php
namespace Roman;

class MyLibrary
{
    public function hello()
    {
        return 'hello';
    }
}
```

Notice that I added a namespace (Roman) just to distinguish your code from Symfony's.

Now you need to tweak composer.json in order to allow php to autoload your classes:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/",
            "Roman\\": "lib/"
        }
    },
```

After adding the Roman line, run "composer dump-autoload" to regenerate the autoload files.

After that, it's just a question of using regular php inside of your application:

```
# src/Controller/DefaultController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Roman\MyLibrary;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DefaultController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $myLibrary = new MyLibrary();
        $hello = $myLibrary->hello();
        return new Response($hello);
    }
}
```

And that should get your started.

Comment: Thanks Cerad, I see your point and I've managed to get it work. 

So at the end it comes down to either I use my own libraries in a namespace App\lib - I've figured this is the only way they autoload load in src folder (PSR4 thing!), either I fall down to command line (that I don't want to) which alters autoloader behavior (that I also don't want to). 

I have to rethink which is more worst of these to "bads". :)